# Failed to load driver class org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to configure 2 JNDI datasources in Spring Boot. I tried this configuration:

***application.properties***

```
spring.production-datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/production_gateway
spring.production-datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.warehouse-datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/production_warehouse
spring.warehouse-datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Primary datasource configuration:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.datalis.plugin.production.entity", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "productionEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "productionTransactionManager"
    )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextProductionDatasource {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.production.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties productionDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }   

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.production.datasource")
    public DataSource productionDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionEntityManager") 
    public EntityManager productionEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionTransactionManager")    
    public PlatformTransactionManager productionTransactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionExceptionTranslation")
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor productionExceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Second datasource configuration:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.datalis.plugin.warehouse.entity", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "warehouseEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "warehouseTransactionManager"
    )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextWarehouseDatasource {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "warehouseDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.warehouse.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties warehouseDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "warehouseDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.warehouse.datasource")
    public DataSource warehouseDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "warehouseEntityManager")  
    public EntityManager warehouseEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "warehouseTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager warehouseTransactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "warehouseExceptionTranslation")
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor warehouseExceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

But I get error during deployment:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to set value for property driver-class-name
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$BeanProperty.setValue(JavaBeanBinder.java:349)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:96)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:79)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:56)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:452)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:570)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:556)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.access$400(Binder.java:513)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:450)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:391)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:320)
        ... 132 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$BeanProperty.setValue(JavaBeanBinder.java:346)
        ... 142 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:485)
```

I'm using Spring boot war deployed into Wildfly server with deployed mariadb-java-client-2.4.2.jar. It's working fine when I use single datasource configuration. But with second datasource I get exception.

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

***Second attempt***:

***application.properties:***

```
spring.production.datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/production_gateway
spring.production.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.production.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.production.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.production.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.warehouse.datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/production_warehouse
spring.warehouse.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.warehouse.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.warehouse.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.warehouse.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

First datasource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.datalis.plugin.production.entity", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "productionEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "productionTransactionManager"
    )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextProductionDatasource {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.production")
    public DataSourceProperties productionDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }   

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.production")
    public DataSource productionDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionEntityManager") 
    public EntityManager productionEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionTransactionManager")    
    public PlatformTransactionManager productionTransactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionExceptionTranslation")
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor productionExceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Second datasource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.datalis.plugin.warehouse.entity", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "warehouseEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "warehouseTransactionManager"
    )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextWarehouseDatasource {

    @Bean(name = "warehouseDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.warehouse")
    public DataSourceProperties warehouseDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "warehouseDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.warehouse")
    public DataSource warehouseDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "warehouseEntityManager")  
    public EntityManager warehouseEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "warehouseTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager warehouseTransactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "warehouseExceptionTranslation")
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor warehouseExceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Now I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at deployment.datalis_rest_api.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
```

Comment: There's more to that exception stack. Please post the full thing.

Comment: Now I get this error stack:  pastebin.com/031gkhaz

Comment: You don't have url in datasource configuration

Comment: Your url is not shown here, what I think the problem is at your url. Was it a mysql url instead of mariadb url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

correct the name of both entityManager beans: productionEntityManager and warehouseEntityManager

`entityManagerFactoryRef` in `@EnableJpaRepositories` is the beanName reference,

so use

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.datalis.plugin.production.entity", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "productionEntityManager",  
        transactionManagerRef = "productionTransactionManager" 
    )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextProductionDatasource {

  ...

 @Primary
    @Bean   
    public EntityManager productionEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.datalis.plugin.warehouse.entity", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "warehouseEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "warehouseTransactionManager"
    )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextWarehouseDatasource {

   ...

    @Bean   
    public EntityManager warehouseEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
```

you need to match the property-name in `@ConfigurationProperties` to the value of properties '**-**' versus '**.**'

use  `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.production-datasource")` and
`@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.warehouse-datasource")`

and make sure you have have driver in your classpath

like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: 'Failed to load driver class org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver' ... did you provide a dependency with the driver for MariaDB?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine with single datasource. I have deployed the jdbc.jar driver into Wildfly.(I'm using spring as deployeble war into Wildfly server )

Comment: well, the logging shows: "Failed to load driver class org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader"}}" (line 289)

Comment: Maybe this configuration value is not correct `spring.production-datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`? When I use only `spring.satasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver` it's working fine.

Comment: glad you got it working, please accept my answer if it was useful

Comment: no, I didn't managed to make it working. Any idea how to specify the jdbc driver for each connection?

Comment: Oh? When I use only `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver` it's working fine...

Comment: and if you only provide a JNDI-name? (basically, the only thing that actually needed)

Comment: I updated the post with the latest issue. Any idea why the jdbc driver is not found?

Comment: Thanks, now I get a new error. Can you take a look please?

Answer (score 2):

In your properties you are using `spring.production-datasource` however in the Spring `@Configuration` you are attempting to map it with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.production.datasource")`. Starting from Spring Boot 2 the relaxed property binding rules [are now more strict](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#relaxed-binding) so there is a mismatch between a dash and a dot here.

You either need to change properties to `spring.production.datasource` or use  `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.production-datasource")`.

When configuring Spring Boot `DataSource` you can either use `jndi-name` or provide the connection details, not both. As per [Common Application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html):

> spring.datasource.jndi-name
>
> JNDI location of the datasource. Class, url, username & password are ignored

You most likely have to remove `spring.production-datasource.driver-class-name` property as it collides with `jndi-name`.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get a error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
` Do you know how this can be fixed?

Comment: Updated answer with my guess, you have a strange setup. You should debug Spring Boot code to find where the exception is thrown.

Comment: I remove the class-name..... property but again I get `dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.` Let me start the app in debug mode I will upload the result.

Comment: Don't post debug log here, use a breakpoint and understand the code with [a debugger](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html).

Comment: Well I can see this: `ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - HikariPool-1 - dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.`

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I'm complete newbie to Spring Boot, H2, Maven, etc.)

Just my 2c in case some other newbie lands on this question page after having gotten this particular error:

I got this error immediately after having added the dependency to `pom.xml` and needed properties into the `application.properties` file.

Trying to run the application from Eclipse IDE would just fail with this `Failed to load driver class org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver` error. My first thought was that maybe Maven didn't pick up the dependency for some reason, but the `mariadb-java-client.jar` file was in `~/.m2/repository/org/mariadb/jdbc`, thus I assumed everything was correct there.

Quick googling showed there should not be much else to do, it just should work(tm). I was out of ideas and semi-randomly invoked `mvnw clean install` from shell, and everything worked just fine there - the application started as it should.

Empowered by this massive random success, I closed & reopened the project in Eclipse. Lo and behold; magically everything started working there as well.