# How to solve the error mariadb jdbc driver white spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I try to run my application but there is this error which prevents me from doing that here is the error:

```
   > java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@2626b418;ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@2626b418
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:292)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:744)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:676)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:483)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:560)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:244)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:96)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:857)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1017)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:557)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:922)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@2626b418;ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@2626b418
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:56)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:281)
        ... 28 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:38)
        ... 29 more
    
    Feb 18, 2020 10:36:48 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
    WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
    java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@2626b418;ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@2626b418
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:292)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:744)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:676)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:483)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:560)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:244)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:96)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:857)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1017)
```

I already added the jar mariadb here:

[jar mariadb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRk3K.png)

and also the dependecy:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

and this is my file properties :

```
        label.firstname=First Name
    label.lastname=Last Name
    label.email=Email
    label.telephone=Telephone
    label.add=Add Employee
     
     
     
     
     label.nom= NOM
     label.addp=Add Personne
     
     
    label.menu=Actions
    label.title=Employee Form
    label.footer=&copy; www.HowToDoInJava.com
spring.production.datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/production_gateway
spring.production.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.production.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.production.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.production.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

help me please

I've been trying to start the application for 2 hours but without success, I think there is something missing that prevents me from doing this.

Your help will be very precious to me, I look forward to your response !!

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58999473/failed-to-load-driver-class-org-mariadb-jdbc-driver ?

Comment: Hi! Please, could you add your properties file to the question? Maybe your code is not picking up the configuration (spring.datasource.driver-class-name...)?

Comment: it's good i added the file properties in the question

Comment: Where are datasource properties

Comment: I found a properties code for mariadb I added it in my properties file (I wanted to specify that I am a beginner in spring) so I still did not understand 100%

Comment: try to follow this url: https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-mariadb/