# ConcurrentModificationException in batch application after upgrading project to springboot 2.7.13

Tags: spring, spring-boot, upgrade, concurrentmodification

ConcurrentModificationException in batch application after upgrading project to springboot 2.7.13
Heres the full stack trace

```
2023-10-10 11:55:10.091  INFO 10D2L91PXXP3 --- [  restartedMain] c.d.i.c.p.b.CustomSecurityFilter                   : Into init method: 
2023-10-10 11:55:10.154  INFO 10D2L91PXXP3 --- [  restartedMain] c.d.i.c.p.j.u.DataSourceUtil                       : Into getJdbcDataSource method with countrycd : in, schema : gui
2023-10-10 11:55:10.169  INFO 10D2L91PXXP3 --- [  restartedMain] c.d.i.c.p.j.u.DataSourceUtil                       : Configured datasource: IN. Connection poolname:gui.in-connection-pool
2023-10-10 11:55:10.254  WARN 10D2L91PXXP3 --- [  restartedMain] c.z.h.HikariConfig                                 : gui.in-connection-pool - idleTimeout has been set but has no effect because the pool is operating as a fixed size pool.
2023-10-10 11:55:11.296 ERROR 10D2L91PXXP3 --- [  restartedMain] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                                 : gui.in-connection-pool - Exception during pool initialization.
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.util.Hashtable$Enumerator.next(Hashtable.java:1387)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Configuration.mapPropertiesToOption(Configuration.java:611)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Configuration.parseInternal(Configuration.java:589)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:518)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:96)
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:27)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:337)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DatabaseDriver.fromDataSource(DatabaseDriver.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.getDatabaseDriver(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.determinePlatform(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.lambda$resolveAll$0(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.resolveAll(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.resolveAll(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.resolveSchemaLocations(BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.getSettings(BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.<init>(BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration.batchDataSourceInitializer(BatchAutoConfiguration.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:910)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at com.paymt.Application.main(Application.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
2023-10-10 11:55:11.317  WARN 10D2L91PXXP3 --- [  restartedMain] AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'batchDataSourceInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
2023-10-10 11:55:11.468 ERROR 10D2L91PXXP3 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.SpringApplication                            : Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'batchDataSourceInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:910)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at com.Application.main(Application.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'batchDataSourceInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.determinePlatform(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:132)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.lambda$resolveAll$0(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.resolveAll(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.resolveAll(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.resolveSchemaLocations(BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.getSettings(BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.<init>(BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration.batchDataSourceInitializer(BatchAutoConfiguration.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

I have tried add excluding the BatchAutoConfiguration, IntegrationAutoConfiguration classes

having the properties as

### JDBC configuration is as :

in.app.datasources.gui.jdbc.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/[db]

app.datasources.gui.jdbc.username=root

app.datasources.gui.jdbc.password=

app.datasources.gui.jdbc.driver.class=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

app.datasources.gui.jdbc.max.connections=5

added the following in app properties file
  `spring.batch.initialize-schema=never (also tried always)`

also tried downgrading version of mariadb to
2.6.2 and 3.0.9 still no luck

Comment: Upgrading from which version?

Comment: check below link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58999473/failed-to-load-driver-class-org-mariadb-jdbc-driver hope this helps.